# How to safely save file to disk without the risk of windows reject it?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, filenames

I'm developing a winform application. I want to take input from user (i.e. the user provides username) and use that input as part of filename and save to file.

How do I check if the username provided by the user didn't contain windows' reserved characters. And what is the list of reserved characters for windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

via:

```
    Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
```

and

```
    Path.GetInvalidPathChars()
```

The exact list *could* be platform-specific (especially for mono), and it includes some non-printable characters... so showing you them here is tricky ;p